# The cordova navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition api always return error code 3

Tags: cordova, geolocation, ibm-mobilefirst

When I develop the standard hybrid app using worklight, and I use the sample code as following, but I can not get the position information on device, even if I am on the street. It always return err code 3. it can success one in many times. Can you help how to make it works? I test on Worklight 6.1 and 6.2, the same issue.

I test on Android device Samsung S3.

Thanks.

```
var onSuccess = function(position) {
    alert('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
          'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
          'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
          'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
          'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
          'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
          'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
          'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp                + '\n');
};

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
```

Comment: try this code and let me know. `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 30000,
  maximumAge: 30000
});`

Answer (score 0):

PositionError code 3 is for Timeout. You may want to try Bluewings suggestion. Also note that you can try using the WL.Device.Geo.acquirePosition API instead.

Answer (score 0):

Code 3 - Timeout.

Set higher timeout time:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    onSuccess, 
    onError, 
    {
        **timeout: 10000**, 
        maximumAge: Infinity
    };
)
```